# How to rotate device screen from landscape to portrait in tizen web application?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I am developer tizen consumer tv web app.How should i rotate the screen (toggle orientation) by code.

Please help us in this.
Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: have you checked the answer ?

Comment: Hello...have you checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Lock the screen with the `lockOrientation()` method.

The following code snippet demonstrates how to lock the screen to a specified orientation.

```
screen.lockOrientation("portrait-secondary");
```

The method accepts the following parameter values: `portrait-primary, portrait-secondary, landscape-primary, landscape-secondary, portrait, and landscape.`

> Note:
>
> > When using the screen orientation lock:
> >     When the portrait value is used to lock the orientation, the orientation can change between portrait-primary and portrait-secondary. The landscape value behaves similarly.
> >     Depending on the browser, unlocking the screen orientation may have no visual effect.

For more follow [this](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/device/screen-orientation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for rotate the device form Landscape to portrait .

```
b2bapis.b2bcontrol.setMenuOrientation("DEGREE_90",onSuccessSettingMenuOrientation,onErrorSettingMenuOrientation);

b2bapis.b2bcontrol.setSourceOrientation("TV","DEGREE_90", onSuccessSettingOrientation, onErrorSettingOrientation);
```

Note: need to add privileges in config.xml

Comment: Would really like to know what the privileges are